# Continuous deployment on multiple azure VM

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

we are developing a product where we need to create separate VM for each client. now, we need to deploy code and install packages on the every newly created vm. We are able to create VM using Azure python SDK, need help on deploying code and package installation on the new VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Azure custom script extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/extensions-customscript) to install your software.

> The Custom Script Extension downloads and executes scripts on Azure
>   virtual machines. This extension is useful for post deployment
>   configuration, software installation, or any other configuration /
>   management task. Scripts can be downloaded from Azure storage or other
>   accessible internet location, or provided to the extension run time.

In your scenario, you need write a script to deploy code and package.

If you want to use python to do this, please refer to this [python sdk documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.compute.compute.v2017_03_30.operations.virtualmachineextensionsoperations?view=azure-python#azure_mgmt_compute_compute_v2017_03_30_operations_VirtualMachineExtensionsOperations_create_or_update).

Comment: could you please help us on how to do continuous deployment of code from git as we will have to deploy code changes across all VM's.

Comment: @TailorDevendra I am not work on Git, you could ask the question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am not sure it [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-jenkins-github-docker-cicd) is you need. For Linux VM, you could use `Jenkins` to CI/CD.